# Mysql/php bind_param set null

Tags: php, mysql

It is saying "Error: Column 'DeliveredDate' cannot be null."

```
$delivereddate = null;
$stmt = $connection->prepare("INSERT INTO orders (receiptid, date, cid, cardno, expirydate,      expecteddate, delivereddate) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
$stmt->bind_param("sssssss", $receiptid, $date, $cid, $cardno, $expirydate, $expecteddate, $delivereddate);
```

The related table is:

```
CREATE TABLE Orders(
ReceiptId char(30) not null,
Date date not null,
CId char(30) not null,
CardNo char(30) not null,
ExpiryDate date not null,
ExpectedDate date not null,
DeliveredDate date, 
PRIMARY KEY(ReceiptId));
```

I tried inserting values in mysql workbench and I can do:

```
INSERT INTO orders VALUE
(1, '2012-12-10', 1, 1, '2014-2-3', '2012-12-23', null);
```

Comment: Oh is that not the proper way to do it? Sorry I'm very new to this... what should the proper format be?

Comment: pass some values to `$delivereddate`

Comment: I was wrong, you were fine. I use a different method.

Comment: Could you please post the values of the variables as you are trying to assign them? It looks to me like one of the variables you are passing doesn't have the value you think it does.

Comment: Pretty sure all you need to do is change `DeliveredDate date` to `DeliveredDate date NULL`

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$delivereddate = '2014-11-26 10:40:35';  // some date
$stmt = $connection->prepare("INSERT INTO orders (receiptid, date, cid, cardno, expirydate,      expecteddate, delivereddate) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
$stmt->bind_param("sssssss", $receiptid, $date, $cid, $cardno, $expirydate, $expecteddate, $delivereddate);
```

I think the error is due to `$delivereddate = null;`

comment for errors...

Comment: So am I not allowed to set delivereddate to equal null? It has to be some value?

Comment: Oh that should work, but I just wanted to see if it could be set to null. Thanks :D

Comment: check whether it allows empty value (i.e) `$delivereddate = '';`

Answer (score 1):

Just change your table `sql` to allow `NULL` for the `DeliveryDate` column.

```
CREATE TABLE Orders(
ReceiptId char(30) not null,
Date date not null,
CId char(30) not null,
CardNo char(30) not null,
ExpiryDate date not null,
ExpectedDate date not null,
DeliveredDate date null, 
PRIMARY KEY(ReceiptId));
```

And the rest should work. (provided you want to store `null` in that column)